# Unable to launch EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to launch an EC2 instance, but I'm getting the following error message and don't know what to make out of it.

```
Each network interface requires either a subnet or a network interface ID.
```

I tried to find similar posts but couldn't. Please could someone help me out.
Thanks

Comment: How many network interfaces did you specify on the EC2 instance? Are you launching into a VPC or EC2-Classic?

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue.

I got it working using the classic wizard to create the instance rather than the quick launch - it gave me an option to select a subnet that way. Try using the classic wizard to create it (as long as you have an existing key it shouldn't give you too big of a problem).

Comment: You are right, it worked. But still I dont understand what the problem is. I never had this problem earlier.

Answer (score 0):

In the wizard I chose not to auto-assign a public IP, because my instance should not be accessibly from the internet.  The error message suggests that a subnet should be enough, but I could only get past this error by adding a public IP on the "instance details" tab.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to not specify the subnet or security groups under the "Network settings" section, and instead specify them under the "Network interfaces" section.

Answer (score 0):

As I was in a learning stage, By changing the **auto-assign-public-ip** to enable Works for me. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Open the Advanced network configuration and only choose **Enable** for **Auto-assign public IP** and **No** for **Delete on termination** option

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/create-launch-template.html#change-network-interface